# Add custom workflow to "Create project" screen

Tags: jira

is there a way to add custom workflow to "Create new project" screen?

http://s13.postimg.org/f1acwcerr/Untitled_1.jpg - create new project screen

Or make my custom workflow to be default, but seems that it's not possible at the moment.

The problem is that I created a workflow that suits my needs better than those which are available by default at marketplace. I would like to use this workflow as default for all projects. Or have an easy way to create a new project based on my custom workflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to set a user created workflow as the default but there is a issue opened with Atlassian created about it. (See [JRA-9363](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-9363))

Your only option would be to create the project and then immediately change over its Workflow Scheme to be that of your custom one that has the custom workflow associated to it.

Comment: Yes, I know about this issue and I already voted for it. The title of that issue is a bit different and I thought you can just add your workflow to create project screen.
Damn atlassian... their products are good, but usability isn't always planned well.